# Get foregin key value not id SQL

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, inner-join

guys php beginner is here :)

i know my question has been asked a lot, but i read more than 20 answers & most of them not working with my query, and my query is simple but i don't know why didn't work with me :(,

i  have 2 TABLE :

1- **USERS** : (id,username,country,status) primary key is **id** & foregin key is **country**

2- **countries** (country_id,country_en,country_code) primary key is **country_id**

when i insert data into countries table & inserting data into users everything FINE & CONNECTED to each other!

but when i came to query part here 's my problem : 
everything here is working! **but** the country output value is ID & i want it to be the name of it because the country_en has name values

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` 
        WHERE `users`.`status` = 'active' 
        ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10 ";
```

after i read many question's answers i tried to add UNION, LEFT JOIN, etc.. but still the same & i know the problem from my & i will learn from my mistakes
final query that i tried to solve this issue

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`status` = 'active' 
        INNER JOIN `countries` ON `users`.`country` = `countries`.`country_en` 
        ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10 ";
```

could you guys help me with it :(

Comment: What is `country_en` field ? you JOIN  using this field, I guess it must be : `INNER JOIN countries ON users.country = countries.country_id`

Comment: @VincentDecaux country_en is (varchar), when i tried your query is giving me (: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in on line 
)

Comment: shouldnt you JOIN on `countries.country_id` instead of `countries.country_en`? You should show some data to help us visualize the issue, its a bit unclear atm.

Comment: Give us an example of table data from both the target table and the joined table. If you want to return the data of `country` by name and not by id, we are going to need to see a table row from each table so that we know how to help you formulate your query

Comment: @ThomasG thank you, i will take a pic of the both tables & insert it here may it help 

Comment: @DrewT exactly that what im looking for, output i want it to be the value not the id , i will take pic of the both tables may it help, regarding to you & other's 

Comment: @ThomasG  for the key's : ibb.co/tZ2B79v ibb.co/RCNJKLp ibb.co/xfLny6m for both tables : ibb.co/FYC8KwM ibb.co/3r7ySP4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank to each of you for trying helping me,

i would like to share with all of you the answer of my question with the best method to fetch the data of foregin key not the ID only, the method use "**JOIN**"

> *minitauros says:* **JOIN** works **if** tables have **different column names**. BELOW THE **FINAL QUERY**

```
SELECT `users`.`id`, `users`.`username`, `users`.`country`, `users`.`status`, `countries`.`country_id`, `countries`.`country_en` FROM `users` JOIN `countries` ON `users`.`id` = `countries`.`country_id` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1
```

In the ON part of the query you tell the query **which column** in the **first table** **matches** the which column in the **second table**.

credit to [minitauros](https://www.daniweb.com/members/902965/minitauros)

[The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns?](https://www.daniweb.com/posts/jump/2189427)

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT users.username,users.country,user.status,countries.country_en 
    FROM users 
    INNER JOIN countries ON users.country = countries.country_id 
    WHERE users.status = 'active' 
    ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10 ";
```

You are however open to sql injection so do look at prepared statements

Comment: thanks for your alert, i will convert it at all but first i start with simple query to get understanding with how work with it , much love 